# mediaelement.js and Iscroll.js iphone

Tags: mediaelement.js, mediaelement, iscroll4, iscroll

I'm using `mediaelement.js` to display videos in a div scollable with `Iscroll.js`, it works perfect on ipad but on iphone I can't scroll the page touching the video.

What is the difference between ipad and iphone behaviour with `mediaelement.js` ?

You can see the project here (clic on the "video" button on the left bottom corner)
http://www.360images.fr/step/mobile.html

Thanx !

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing this issue, too. It seems that mejs disables touch interactions for the whole area over the video on iPhone, but not on iPad - The behaviour can be forced on iPad by using setting the "iPadUseNativeControls" to true, so I assume that it may be something to do with the native controls, or some of the script that mejs is using in conjunction with them.

I've had a little rummage around in the js, and can't find anything that immediately jumps out at me as to why this would prevent touch interaction. I have raised an issue on the github project, so will see what response (if any) comes from that.